# Convert Array to List in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I try to do this with (same as java)

```
val disabledNos = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
var integers = Arrays.asList(disabledNos)
```

but this doesn't give me a list.
Any ideas?

Comment: The main problem why it didn't work in the first place, was, that you basically created a `List<IntArray>`. You need to use the [spread operator (`*`)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs) to get a `List<Int>`, i.e. the following would have worked too: `val integers = Arrays.asList(*disabledNos)`. A similar question, that also mentions the actual error: [Convert `Array<String>` to `ArrayList<String>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55451118/convert-arraystring-to-arrayliststring)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Kotlin support in the standard library this conversion.

You can use directly

```
disableNos.toList()
```

or if you want to make it mutable:

```
disableNos.toMutableList()
```

Answer (score 2):

This will fix your problem :

```
val disabledNos = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
var integers = Arrays.asList(*disabledNos)
```

Just add * to this to asList

Answer (score 0):

Oops that was very simple:

```
var integers = disabledNos.toList()
```

Comment: This will give you `List<IntArray>` instead of `List<Int>`. @crgarridos's answer is correct.

Comment: Oh boy I forgot to remove Arrays.asList() while posting the answer :(