# Convert Array<String> to ArrayList<String>

Tags: arraylist, kotlin

How do I convert `Array<String>` to `ArrayList<String>` in Kotlin?

```
var categoryList : ArrayList<String>?=null
val list = arrayOf("None", "ABC")
categoryList = ArrayList(Arrays.asList(list))
```

I receive this error:

**Error**

```
Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is kotlin.collections.ArrayList<Array<String>!> /* = java.util.ArrayList<Array<String>!> */ but kotlin.collections.ArrayList<String>? /* = java.util.ArrayList<String>? */ was expected
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create ArrayList from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/create-arraylist-from-array)

Comment: @Roland Sorry my bad , he tagged it as java first , I should have saw the complete code properly .  In this case its duplicate of [Convert Array to List in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46662513/convert-array-to-list-in-kotlin)

Comment: @ManoharReddy no problem... just saw that edit after my comment ;-) ... well... definitely similar... but... it defines a type here beforehand and gets the wrong one there... the same problem is underneath, but 2 different starting points in my opinion... I really was looking for a question mentioning that error message, but couldn't find one... wondering why the spread operator wasn't mentioned in the linked question....

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You may be interested in [`toCollection`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-collection.html#tocollection) to add the elements to any collection you pass:

```
categoryList = list.toCollection(ArrayList())
```

Note that to fix your specific problem you just need the [spread operator (`*`)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs). With the `*`-fix applied it would have worked too:

```
categoryList = ArrayList(Arrays.asList(*list))
```

Comment: maybe you are also interested in just [`list.toMutableList()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-mutable-list.html#tomutablelist). it depends whether you really need that `ArrayList` ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Hope it'll help.

```
var categoryList : ArrayList<String>?=null
val list = arrayOf("None", "ABC")
categoryList = list.toCollection(ArrayList())
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is use `arrayListOf`

```
 categoryList =arrayListOf("None", "ABC")
```

Answer (score 0):

The spread operator and `arrayListOf` is another option:

```
var categoryList : ArrayList<String>?=null
val list = arrayOf("None", "ABC")
categoryList = arrayListOf(*list)
```

Answer (score -1):

```kotlin
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList

var arr:List<String>=["one","two"]<br>
val array_list:ArrayList<String>=ArrayList(arr)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Comment: Notably, given that this answer is two years old, has three existing answers, including an accepted answer, it'd be useful to help explain under what circumstances your approach is preferred, and why it's different from the existing answers.